# how to make value selected from parent component still in child component in angualr4

Tags: angular

i have a parent component ,in that component i use REST  to display values.I select one value from drop down list ,that value is in sidebar ,after routing child component i need to get the same value selected from the parent in the same place in the sidebar
is it possible ?

```
 { path : 'one', component : RunTemp1Component,
  children:[
    { path : 'chart1', component :testComponent,pathMatch:'full'}
    ]}
```

this is my routing

Comment: Please post more of your code

Answer (score 0):

On way is to use global service add provide to this service to you `app.module.ts`

DataService

```
 @Injectable()
    export class DataService {

       public selectedValue:any;

      constructor() { }

    }
```

inject this service in your parent and child componenet, whene you select a value from your select elemnt put the selected value in `selectedValue` property,so when you go the child component you will got the value from this service.

another way to use  route parameter and use **activatedroute** service